# Laravel 5.5 and PHP incompatibility

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to setup a Laravel project in a server which I don't have ssh access, just cPanel access, so I came in with the problem that it seems that the server is not recognizing the right PHP version, Laravel's version I was trying to setup is 5.5. `phpinfo()` outputs version 7.0.22.

Inside cPanel there's a module called "PHP configuration" and it is set to version 7.

How can I solve this problem, I really want to use Laravel 5.5 or above, it is worth mentioning that I don't have contact with the server owner, I'm limited just to cPanel.

It is throwing the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable in /vendor/symfony/translation/Translator.php line 79

which is

```
public function __construct(?string $locale, ...
```

That is how I know it is not recognizing the right php version.

**EDIT:**

Just to clear out, I just thought that was the problem because I have had already that issue sometime in the past and read similar posts, but if that's not the case, I would appreciate that to be pointed out and not just silly jokes like "a bird flew", maybe other people are in the same problem and think of the same reason and this question could be useful to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that the server's PHP version had nothing to do with the problem, the thing was, since I had no access to SSH, I had to install Laravel in my local computer, then copy all the files and put them inside the server, but my computer had PHP 7.1 and although Laravel's version was really version 5.5, some features of PHP 7.1 were applied on that Laravel installation.

So the solution was just to install Laravel 5.5 within a PHP 7.0.* installation in order to make it work in a server with PHP 7.0.22

Related GitHub issue ~ https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23559